# Finite $p$-groups of co-class $3$, class at least $4$ and some controlled generator growth

Tags: finite-groups, p-groups

I am trying to prove the following comment (Ref. https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00605-016-0938-5 Page-684, Rmk3.2):

Let $G$ be a finite $p$-group of co-class $3$, class $\geq 4$. Then $G$ satisfies $d(Z_2(G)/{Z(G)}) = d(G) d(Z(G))$ if and only if $d(G) = 2$. Here $d$ denote the rank of the corresponding group and co-class is $n-c$ if $|G|=p^n$ and $G$ has class $c$.

My attempt is to connect the question to the discussion in the thread: [Groups in which lower central series and upper central series coincide](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/164201/groups-in-which-lower-central-series-and-upper-central-series-coincide)

"$\Rightarrow$" Assuming the condition, we have $d(Z_2(G)/{Z(G)}) \geq 2$. Suppose if possible $|Z_2(G)/{Z(G)}| \geq p^3$. Then we can directly check that $G/Z_{c-1}(G) \cong C_p \times C_p, Z_2(G)/{Z(G)} \cong C^3_p, Z(G) \cong C_p$ and $Z_i(G)/{Z_{i-1}(G)} \cong C_p$ for the remaining upper central quotients. Now since $G$ and $G/{Z(G)}$ has same co-class, using Lem.4.1.13 (Ref. https://books.google.co.in/books/about/The_Structure_of_Groups_of_Prime_Power_O.html?id=34khoLiyP_QC&redir_esc=y) we have $Z(G) = \gamma_c(G)$. At this point proving that $G$ is a UL-group (i.e., the lower and upper central series of $G$ coincide) would imply this side. However, we know that $\gamma_{c+1-i}(G) \subseteq Z_i(G)$ (i.e., gamma-groups are smaller).

I am stuck here. Any ideas?